# How to exclude "outlier" data in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to track some network query responses.

In some cases, data measured is way out of the norm "5x" the normal data. Maybe developer was debugging something, but that data is still getting logged, etc.

Is there a way to exclude outlier data points in Kusto? So they don't impact the p95, p5 numbers?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by checking the value of the 95th percentile of your `metric` in `TableX`

```
let Percentile95 = toscalar(
    TableX
    | summarize percentile(metric, 95));
```

leading to something like [image].
Then you can use this number to filter out the outliers!

```
TableX
| where metric <= Percentile95
```

To filter out both 5% statistical outliers we would therefore use

```
let Percentile05 = toscalar(
    TableX
    | summarize percentile(metric, 5));
let Percentile95 = toscalar(
    TableX
    | summarize percentile(metric, 95));
TableX
| where metric <= Percentile95 and metric >= Percentile5
```